# Session Lost after refresh Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

i have this sets of code with `setsession` and `getsession` in it

```
protected void btnCall_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isCallComplete())
    {
        Collection<Greeting> collGreeting = sessionHelper.GetSession("CurrentGreetingData") as Collection<Greeting>;
        if (collGreeting.Count > 0)
        {
            Collection<CounterbySA> collCounterBySA = new ServiceFacade(User).SelectByFieldName<CounterbySA>("SAID", 106);//CurrentApplicationUser.id
            if (collCounterBySA.Count > 0)
            {
                Counter counter = new ServiceFacade(User).SelectById<Counter>(collCounterBySA[0].CounterID);
                Greeting greeting = collGreeting[0];
                BoardQueue boardQueue = new BoardQueue();

                boardQueue.BranchID = CurrentApplicationUser.BranchID;
                boardQueue.CounterID = counter.ID;
                boardQueue.SAID = 106; //CurrentApplicationUser.ID
                boardQueue.PlatNumber = greeting.PlatNumber;
                boardQueue.Status = (int)CallCustomerStatus.Open;

                ResultStatus rs = new ServiceFacade(User).InsertBoardQueue(boardQueue);
                voiceCall(string.Format("{0}di{1}", greeting.PlatNumber, counter.Name));
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} Silahkan ke {1}", greeting.PlatNumber, counter.Name));

                btnCall.Enabled = false;
                btnReCall.Enabled = true;
                btnComplete.Enabled = true;

                sessionHelper.SetSession("CurrentCallData", boardQueue);
                sessionHelper.SetSession("CurrentGreetingTemp", greeting);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("SA ini Belom terdaftar di Loket, Silahkan ke manu AssignSA untuk mendaftarkan/menempatkan SA ke Loket");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Tidak Ada Customer Untuk Di panggil");
        }
    }
    else if (isCurrentUser())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("sedang memanggil customer, click panggil ulang apabila customer belum datang");

        btnCall.Enabled = true;
        btnReCall.Enabled = true;
        btnComplete.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("SA lain sedang memanggil Customer, harap menunggu");
    }
```

so if i click button call it will set the 2 `session`
and this where i get the session

```
protected void btnReCall_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BoardQueue boardQueue = sessionHelper.GetSession("CurrentCallData") as BoardQueue;
    if (boardQueue != null)
    {
        Counter counter = new ServiceFacade(User).SelectById<Counter>(boardQueue.CounterID);
        voiceCall(string.Format("{0}di{1}", boardQueue.PlatNumber, counter.Name));
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} Silahkan ke {1}", boardQueue.PlatNumber, counter.Name));

        btnNext.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Harap Memanggil Customer terlebih Dahulu");
    }

}
```

Before the page is refresh it works fine. but after the page refresh the session is gone.

i have done some research about this topic but i couldn't get the answer

Here are the get and set method for the session

```
    public void SetSession(string sKey, object sValue)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[sKey] = sValue;
        AddSession(sKey, true);
    }

    public object GetSession(string sKey)
    {
        return ((object)(HttpContext.Current.Session[sKey]));
    }
```

Comment: `MessageBox.Show` in an ASP.Net application? I doubt that will work when you deploy on a server.

Comment: @HansKesting i am doing a web-form based application using asp.net and c#. and it works

Comment: It may seem to work on your dev machine, where the webserver runs on the same machine. But when you deploy to a server, that messagebox tries to show there, not in the browser.

Comment: May be your application pool is being resetting itself causing session loss. In any part your application are you trying to clear/abandon the session.